# BigCommerce Stencil Ratings (Number of Reviews) on Product Card?

Tags: bigcommerce

According to BigCommerce's release notes, the ability to display the number of reviews a given product has was added on 2016-12-22.

It is documented here: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/common-product-card-model

However, I can't get it to work on our store (everything updated to the latest versions, based on Cornerstone 1.4.2)

EDIT: Even on an otherwise exact copy of the latest Cornerstone theme, the `{{ratings}}` handlebar doesn't pull in the number of reviews for a product.

Comment: does the store you are working in have any reviews to show?

Comment: Yes, it shows the star rating, but not the number of reviews. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`rating` in the singular is the aggregate rating, and `ratings` in the plural apparently is not valid, so you should try using `num_reviews` instead.

{{ratings}} appears to be a mistake on the page referenced, and does not appear on the [Product Objects](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/product-resources) page in the BigCommerce documentation. Instead what you see is the same code you'll find if you look at the way the ratings count is shown in `productView.html` (under schema within product details).

`{{product.num_reviews}}`

This same code is given for both ratings count and reviews count (in lines 35 & 36 in the default Cornerstone theme). It makes sense since ratings and reviews go hand-in-hand.